# How to hide Profile2 entity fron user view?

Tags: 7, users

I have a few profile2 types. Profile2 entity is always rendered on standard user view page.

How can I hide this entity? I know I can hide all fields in Manage Display tab, but I wondering if there is a way quicker way.

Answer (score 1):

At admin/people/permissions you can configure what user roles are allowed access to the Profile 2 profiles on a per-profile-type basis. So if you're alright with letting admin users see the profiles, you can hide them for everyone else with the permission controls.

Comment: it's not affect fields from profile2 entities which I'm displaying inside views?

Comment: Don't know. When I have time later I can test. Or you could try it yourself...

Answer (score 1):

Check out these two modules.
1. https://www.drupal.org/project/view_profiles_perms

> This module provides permissions to view user profiles depending on
>   what roles the profile requested to be viewed has.
>
> Use case example: If you want all users to only be able to access
>   profiles of users with the role 'blogger', uncheck 'access user
>   profiles' and check 'access blogger profiles' for anonymous and
>   authenticated users.

2. https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.
>
> Features
>
> Enable field permissions on any entity, not just nodes. Role-based
>   field permissions allowing different viewing patterned based on what
>   access the user has. Author-level permissions allow viewing and
>   editing of fields based on who the entity owner is. Permissions for
>   each field are not enabled by default. Instead, administrators can
>   enable these permissions explicitly for the fields where this feature
>   is needed.